# Azure VM Port Closed while TCPing

Tags: azure, nginx

I have an Azure VM running Ubuntu 14.04. It is running a basic NGINX configuration listening on port 8443 and proxying to localhost 8080 which is being listened to by a service running a script which I am working on.

In my inbound port rules I have opened port 8443 with source IP as my office IP, and destination IP as the VM's private IP, over TCP.

After research I have discovered that you can not ping an Azure VM, though with tools such as *psping* you can check access to specific ports.

Due to being on OSX I have been trying to use [TCPing](https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php), trying both DNS and public IP along with port number. I get the response 'port 8443 closed'.

I have checked ports on my VM with netstat and can confirm that nginx is listening on port 8443 and python (my service running a script) is listening on port 8080.

Here is my sites-enabled nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen       8443;
  server_name myServer;

  index  index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout    600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_http_version    1.1;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      Proxy "";
  }
}
```

Anything else I can check? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check all the following :

- Network Security Groups
- Load Balancer configuration (if exists)
- Configure the Linux Firewall

You can also try to ping the VM port using [PsPing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping) (If your OS is Windows)